# even after installing opencv-contrib modules, i am still not able to run this command?

Tags: opencv

> `recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

It shows error
**AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'face'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

If you are still getting access denied error while installing opencv-contrib-python, use below statement:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --user
```